# Creating simple WPS client?

Tags: python, wps, wpsclient

It looks like the only way to get flat files/data from a WPS service is to use a client.  I'm looking to create a super-simple WPS client in Python 2.6 (or other language) without any dependencies on non-default modules.

Right now I'm gathering resources - I haven't done a lick of coding yet.

Can I use a POST HTTP request with a proper header to request a WPS file?

## Additional Info:

- There's [an OWS LIB example client](https://github.com/geopython/OWSLib/blob/master/examples/wps-client.py), but that requires an OWSlibrary.
- [There's a Javascript/OpenLayers client from PyWPS](http://pywps.wald.intevation.org/documentation/course/client/)  - this looks like its the most independent of external dependencies sans the openlayers.js, but then ... well, OpenLayers is its own client.
- I have the Firefox HTTP Resource Test for POST and GET requests
- I have FireBug

Answer (score 7):

I have done this using urllib2 in python.

Some simple code is

```
import urllib2

request_file = open("my_wps_request.xml", "r")
xml_data = request_file.read()
r = urllib2.Request(
    "http://192.168.109.147:8080/geoserver/wps",
    data=xml_data,
    headers={
        'Content-Type': 'application/xml',
        'Accept' : 'image/tiff'
        })

u = urllib2.urlopen(r)

tiff_file = open('out.tif', 'wb')
tiff_file.write(u.read())
tiff_file.close()
```

I am using geoserver (with python wps extension).

Geoserver Admin page has a Demos -> WPS Request Builder page.
Here you can select a WPS and "Generate XML from process inputs/outputs".

Save the xml into a file (my_wps_request.xml above).

urllib2.request does a POST request with the xml data.
In the above example the returned data is a tif so I just write that to a file.

Even simpler I have used curl

```
curl -u admin:geoserver -H "Content-Type:text/xml" -X POST -d @my_wps_request.xml http://192.168.109.147:8080/geoserver/wps > out.tiff
```